# Facebook Unity plugin: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration:

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm facing a strange Facebook plugin behaviour.

Everything was fine until friday (07/08/2015). I was posting statuses without any problem, but now after I'm entering a login and a password of a test user account (App Settings -> Roles -> Test Users) Facebook showing me an error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. To use this URL you must add a valid native platform in your App's settings.

ATM I'm testing my app for the iOS platform and I can't add it, cause I don't have an app store ID yet.

So what am I supposed to do to test my app's facebook functionality before posting it to the app store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to set up the store id to test the app as long as your app isnt live. At least in my case I remember adding the desired platform from the settings in the facebook dev console , then typing in the Bundle id and saving. after that I was able to test with users added as test users under roles.

Comment: TY, kind sir! I've added an iOS platform without app store id and now my test users are able to post their statuses again!